# django sqlite3 schema name

Tags: django, sqlite, pycharm

I am using django 1.7 and sqlite3. I am creating the database using the following:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.myDBName'),
    }
}
```

I am using pyCharm as the IDE and when I connect to the DB, it says `<unnamed> schema`. I am not sure how to set up schema name? I couldn't find anything here in the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

[image: unnamed schema]

Any suggestions?

Comment: `<unnamed> schema` is one of the few things where I've tried right-clicking and selecting 'Rename' and get an error about not being able to refactor. You can change the name of 'Django default' and all the tables, but not the schema. Is there a reason you want to change it?

Comment: There is no reason.. Its just that looking at unnamed schema is a bit annoying :P